# NativeWifi and Windows XP SP2/SP3

Tags: .net-2.0, windows-xp, wifi, wireless, wlanapi

I'm using the [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and specifically the [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WlanGetNetworkBssList`.

I am aware that that function is not available in Windows XP SP2 and SP3. I tried installing the hotfix that was supposedly to allow access to that function but it did not work.

So are there any Wireless Zero Configuration .NET wrappers out there?

Or more basically, how do I get a list of the basic service set (BSS) entries of the wireless network or networks on a given wireless LAN interface without the use of that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at how [MetaGeek's InSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) does it. It's C#, and [open source (Apache License and available on github)](https://github.com/metageek-llc/inSSIDer-2/blob/master/MetaGeek.WiFi/).

This app is gorgeous and very useful.  There are at least 3 versions.

1. InSSIDer
2. InSSIDer 2
3. InSSIDer forLinux

I've got a vintage XP SP3 here and it works pretty well.  However, I do not think it relies on the WlanGetNetworkBssList API (it's close to the physical interface and besides, I'm using the Intel Wifi management stack (so my ZeroConf service is stopped) and InSSIDer still works).

Comment: Wow! That looks promising! I'm going to check that out in the morning. I'll be sure to report back, and award you the answer if I can indeed get it moving.

Answer (score 0):

There is open source [WLAN API library](https://github.com/maurice2k/wlanapi/) which allows to obtain wireless BSSIDs on Windows XP SP1 and higher by using NDISUIO 5.1 or Wireless Zero Configuration service.

Original code is written in C++ but can be converted into C# for your needs.